# If $s$ is transcendental, is $\frac{1}{s}$ transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

From Wikipedia, the number $3.300330000000000330033\dots$ and its reciprocal $0.30300000303\dots$ are both transcendental. I am wondering:

> If $s$ is transcendental, is $\dfrac 1s$ necessarily transcendental?

I am assuming the answer is not known, with transcendental numbers being complicated and whatnot; if that is the case, is much known about the reciprocal of transcendental numbers? Otherwise, if my suspicion is false, is there a known transcendental number whose reciprocal is a counterexample?

Comment: Suppose that $\frac{1}{s}$ is not transcendental, this is the same as saying $s^{-1}$ is not transcendental. But if $s^{-1}$ is not transcendental, that means it is algebraic. But if $s^{-1}$ is algebraic then given that $(s^{-1})^{-1} = s$ it would mean that the reciprocal of an algebraic number is transcendental.

Comment: If $s$ is algebraic then $1/s$ is also algebraic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is *yes*: If $1/s$ is algebraic, then $p(1/s) = 0$ for some nontrivial polynomial
$$p(x) = a_0 x^0 + \cdots + a_n x^n$$
with rational coefficients. But then
$$0 = s^n p(1/s) = a_0 s^n + \cdots + a_n s^0,$$
which implies that $s$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

The algebraic numbers form a field. Thus, if $1/s$ were algebraic, then $1/(1/s)=s$ would also be algebraic, a contradiction, showing that $1/s$ must be transcendental if $s$ is.

Comment: I don't particularly like this answer, since the proof of algebraic numbers being a field relies on OP's question. This is circular reasoning.